# radio button is not working in jquery innerhtml

Tags: jquery, html, forms, innerhtml

i want to add radio buttons at table data() in a div(students_in_course) but in jquery innerhtml radio button is not showing. if i use type button or text, it will works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("button[name='create_new_take_attendance_button']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var semester_log_id = $(this).attr('id');
   //alert(semester_log_id);

   $.ajax({
    url: "attendance/view_students_in_semester_log/"+semester_log_id,
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
              var totalString ='';
              for(var x=0;x<data.length;x++)
              {
              totalString+='<tr><td>'+data[x].roll_number+'</td><td>'+data[x].full_name+'</td><td><form><input type="radio" name='+x+' value="yes"/>yes<input type="radio" name='+x+' value="no"/>no </form></td></tr>'; // error radio button is not showing
              }
              $('#students_in_course').html(totalString);
              $('#modal_take_attendance').modal('show');
              }
        });
    });  
  });
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML?

Comment: try adding quotes to name, name="'+x+'"

Comment: <table >
                          <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Student Roll</th>
                                                <th>Student Name</th>
                                                <th>Present</th>

                                            </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                            <tbody id="students_in_course">


                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine.

Here is the sample snipped i have tried in JSFiddle. Please refer this.

https://jsfiddle.net/jijith1309/ne4obL7q/

Html

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student Roll</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Present</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="students_in_course"> </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var str = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    str += '<tr><td>123</td><td>jijith</td><td><form><input type="radio" name=' + i + ' value="yes"/>yes<input type="radio" name=' + i + ' value="no"/>no </form></td></tr>'
  }
  $('#students_in_course').html(str);
});
```